# switch two different texts places

Tags: css

I want to change 2 texts places with CSS when I have one that translated to a lang that uses the LTR direction and the second with RTL direction.

This CSS is applied for an email.

this is my code:

```
'<span style="font-weight:bold; text-align: center;">US Cop</span> ' +curIfr.Name
```

curIfr.Name can be RTL lang or LTR lang, and I want to display it on the right side if it RTL and on the left side if it LTR.

The texts are centered inside a card, So I want to keep it centered and just switch the places.

I tried to use

```
'<p style="float:right;"><span style="font-weight:bold; text-align: center;">US Cop</span></p>' +curIfr.Name
```

but since my text is centered, It takes it to the extreme right side and it not keeping it centered.

I also tried to use the direction attribute - But Its do nothing.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @Paulie_D, I kind new to css, I tried to use a float right and the direction as well.
The direction dosnt do nothing to my css some reason - maybe its because this css is apllied for and email - But I dont sure.
About float right - Its place my text to the extrem right and does not keeping it centered.
Sorry for not mention it I will add it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has a `direction` property that sets the direction of the content flow within block-level elements. Values include `rtl` or `ltr`

There's also a HTML element `<bdo>` that can be used like so `<bdo dir="rtl">Some stuff</bdo>`

These are pretty easy to change with Javascript depending on the input. For example, by changing the value of the `direction` property on your span, or the `dir` attribute on the `<bdo>` element.

Edit:

Example:

```
<div style="direction: rtl;">
  <div>Name 1</div>
  <div>Name 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi.. I tried to use direction, but no change to my texts...
Even not with <bdo> tag.. 

'<bdo dir="rtl"><span style="font-weight:bold; text-align: center;">RTLLang</span> </bdo> ' +curIfr.Name 

curIfr.Name  is a LTRLang In this case..

Comment: Hi, you need to apply it on a block level element eg: `<div style="direction:rtl;"><div>Name 1</div><div>Name 2</div></div>`

Comment: Great Thanks a lot.